# Why is a ring that has only one prime helpful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Ireland and Rosen state in *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*:
"We now know that in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $k[x]$ there are infinitely many nonassociate primes. It is instructive to consider a ring where all primes are associate, so that in essence there is only one prime."

They go on to say that if $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime, then $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of all rational numbers $a/b$ so that $p\nmid b$.

What does the statement "... in essence there is only one prime" mean? Why is this kind of ring helpful?

Comment: It means there is only one prime *up to associates*, i.e. you've killed all primes $\neq p$ by adjoing their  inverse, so only $p$ remains (and  all its associates $pn\neq 0$ for $\,p\nmid n).\,$ This is a special case of [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)).

Comment: One reason such localizations are useful here is that for many divisibility problems we can reduce "global" problems to simpler "local" problems in these localizations - analogous to how we solve many problems in $\Bbb Z$ by working one prime at a time.

Comment: A general example is the class of [Krull domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_ring), which include UFDs, Dedekind domains, and Noetherian integrally closed domains. Here the localizations $D_{\cal P}$ at minimal prime ideals $\cal P$ are [DVRs = discrete valuation rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring) where divisibility is particular simple because ideals are totally ordered by inclusion, as in your example  $\,up^j\mid vp^k\iff (p^j)\supset (p^k) \iff  j\le k.\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two elements $a,b$ of a ring $R$ are said to be *associate* if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$. So, for example, in $\mathbb{Z}$, $7$ and $-7$ are associate. In this case (obviously) we can always write $b = ua$ for some unit $u$.

Now, on to your question. If *all primes in a ring $R$ are associate*, we can say that there is really a unique prime element $p$, and the rest are some unit multiple of this prime element (can be written as $up$ for some unit $u$). So, in this sense, we can say that indeed there is only one prime, because note that there is only one prime ideal (the one generated by $p$).

Why is it useful to study these kinds of rings? Well, it depends, obviously. I can’t give you a satisfactory answer. However, note that some really unique things happen in these kinds of rings. For example, if the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic holds (i.e., we are in a UFD) then every element of the UFD can be expressed as a power of $p$ times a unit.

I hope my answer helped.

Comment: It did help, thank you so much.

Comment: Would this be a working example? Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}_7$. $4/29$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ since $4/29\cdot29/4=1$. Does the "power of $p$ times a unit" apply here in the sense that$4/29=7^0\cdot4/29$?

Comment: @DullandWitlessBoi Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a while since I thought in terms of abstract algebra.